# How to route data from default port to another[4001]

Tags: go

currently my go server is running on port 4001 for https request. to access web application i need to type domainname:4001 in browser.

I would like only to type domainname ato make the connection to web server on port 40001.

Comment: You can't. The default HTTP port is 80. Either you need an external proxy of some kind or you need to modify your app to listen on port 80.

Comment: i modified it to listen directly for 443 for https , i got an error "HTTPS port 443 is not accessible
"

Comment: Then the port is in use by another process, or you need elevated privileges to use it (eg on Linux, ports below 1024 require root).

Comment: thanks Adrian that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You may either use `iptables` or modify your program to listen on :80 (HTTP) or :443 (HTTPS).

With iptables, these commands will redirect all :80 and :443 traffic on your server to :8080 and :8443 respectively, internally.

`sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443`

You may need to install `iptables`. Run `sudo apt install iptables`.

This is a temporal fix. To make it permanent, put those lines in your `~/.bashrc`

If you don't want to use `iptables`, then modify the ports your program is listening on. However, remember that ports under 1024 need root permissions, so you'll need to run the program as root.